# ISDN, DSL, Circuit Switching and Package Switching

Tags: switching, adsl, packet-path

I need a bit of help to clarify the above-mentioned terms. From my reading, I can see that both ISDN and DSL are used over telephone copper lines. However, ISDN is associated with circuit switching and DSL with package switching. What does that mean? Does it have to do with how the information is transmitted after it has reached the core network?

Comment: @Zac67 I had seen this question that you posted. I would also like however to additionally understand the connection of switching types with ISDN and DSL technologies.

Comment: That's a whole new question to be posted. However, you'll need to be much more specific what you mean by "connection of switching types".